# How to Insert/Update/Delete in one Ajax POST

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a user modifiable table where — technically — in one session a user could retrieve a previously saved session and insert a new row, update a row, and delete a row.

Currently, on save, I am deleting all rows of the previous session and simply using INSERT to add all the rows all over again (see code below).

While this works, it just seems wrong somehow. I'm thinking that I should be using a combination of INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE to do this correctly? What is the best method to do this? Can it be done with a single Ajax POST and, if so, do I then perform three separate queries based on the need to INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE? Of course, that will mean trying to keep track of the status of each row throughout a session. I'm hoping there's a simply (recommended) way to do this. Thank you for any direction you can provide.

```
$sql_delete = "DELETE FROM worksheet_1_1b WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql_delete);

    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO worksheet_1_1b (user_id, key_position, area, ro, span, criteria1, criteria2, criteria3, urgency) VALUES ('$user_id','$key_position','$area','$ro','$span','$criteria1','$criteria2','$criteria3','$urgency' )";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql_update);
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and looks clunky and out of place when used in new code.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: Thank you for your sage advice. As I'm learning PHP it's these "stumbles" that help point me in the right direction. I have read a great deal on the SQL injection issues and my plan was to incorporate recommended practices once I had things running. With that said I was not as familiar with your second 'note' so that is an area that I will now focus on. I appreciate your input very much. Thank you.

Comment: SQL injection is something that's easily prevented and will *save time* going forward. Leaving these bugs for later means you could forget, or you could end up in trouble before you can do anything to fix it. Do it right the first time. You won't regret it.

Comment: A PHP script can make as ,any queries as it likes, of any type, in response to one AJAX call. It's not clear to me what constitutes a 'session' in your question, or what rows you're storing, or where.

Comment: Consider whether you really want a user to be able to hard delete data in this way

Comment: @tadman Very good advice. I wasn't being "lazy" but clearly my priorities were backwards.

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular Thank you for clarifying the number of queries the PHP script can make. In regard to what constitutes a 'session' I was considering anytime a user retrieves previous input and makes any changes whatsoever (e.g., edit, delete, add) and then 'saves' again as a 'session.'

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure what you mean by "whether you really want a user to be able to hard delete data in this way" because in my application the user offers input within a table, saves the file, and can retrieve it later to edit any of their previous entries. One of those function should be to delete a row if it's no longer applicable or necessary, shouldn't it?

Comment: It's not what I'd do, but it's your system, not mine.

Comment: @Strawberry Okay ... I'm intrigued ... if I'm heading in the wrong direction I'm certainly open. I assumed that a user may want to delete something he/she previously entered to ensure the data is correct. But you're saying "It's not what you would do." So what would you do instead? If it makes any difference, the data being entered has to do with the selection of employees for succession purposes. If an employee is entered and, later, retracted, then a delete is what I'm thinking is necessary.I am still learning (obviously) so any gems thrown my way are welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Obviously you will have a back up. Even so, it's so easy to accidentally delete more than was intended, and when you DELETE, you lose both the entry itself, and its relationships (which isn't the case with UPDATE), plus there's no 'undo'. Sometimes, there's a solid case for DELETE, and there may even be (in some instances) a legal requirement to provide it, but generally, I prefer that users cannot delete relationships. Instead, consider updating a status flag that changes from 'active' to 'hidden' or 'deleted'.

Comment: With regards to sql injection, incorporating 'recommended practices' now actually makes your code cleaner and easier to write.

Comment: Okay, I now see what you are recommending and I see the wisdom behind it. Creating a status flag eliminates the risk of DELETE and still allows me to only show the user those rows that are active. Thank you for taking the time to explain. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spitballing, here: I think this is a solid case for an architecture which makes use to two way bindings (Angular springs to mind) to keep the DB in sync with the UI.

However, if you're determined to run this via AJAX calls, you could fairly easily wrap all the CRUD requests into a single `data` object, and then parse it (after retrieving it from `$_POST`) from there, being sure to escape your values and insert them into parameterized queries to ameliorate SQL injection based attack vectors.

A data structure like

```
{data=
    {
        create={
            /*some data in whatever format*/
        },
        update={
            /*some data in whatever format*/
        },
        delete={
            /*some data in whatever format*/
        }
    }
}
```

would be an option, for example.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to describe a possible solution to my question. I was thinking too linearly in configuring the "data" for my Ajax Post. I can clearly see the logic in your suggested approach. I will give this approach a try. Out of curiosity, and only if you have a minute, is there anything inherently wrong in what I was originally doing as described in my question (simply deleting all rows and then inserting them again when a user wants to save his/her table entries)?

Comment: Inherently wrong? Nah. And, frankly, that's what I'd do when I started prototyping a solution. But I've been working with, uh, "applications of scale" lately, which makes me awfully concerned with the total data sent over the wire. Altering *just* what needs to be altered saved a lot of bits in the network.

Comment: Thank you for conserving some of those "bits" for me ... I appreciate all the information (learning) here. Thank you!